# How to I simplify code that combines information and adds up values for certain columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I am revamping some VBA code that was done 15 years ago that someone else created. I have to add more code to fit our needs but I exceed the amount of code allowed to run.

I have a Products in Column "AF" with the Values I need to Combine together in Column "AH" "AL" and "AN" mostly. The rest of the columns don't need to add. Have it input the range of data in a different part of the worksheet.

The first part of the Code Clears out previous data so its clean.

Second part of the code looks for a Tile in Column AF and searches rows 41-60 for the same tile once it finds another one (or if it doesn't) it puts in some row in column A and some row in the 41-60 range. This repeats over and over till it goes though all the rows. This one works but once it goes to 41-62 adding in additional lines it doesn't work.

```
Private Sub FloorWallTileCombo_Click()
Dim TileSearch As String
Dim TotalPrice As Double, TotalSF As Double, TotalSurCap As Double, TotalCorCap As Double
'Dim TotalLF As Double, TotalAccentPcs As Double
For j = 41 To 60
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(j, "A") = ""
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(j, "D") = ""
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(j, "E") = ""
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(j, "F") = ""

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(j, "H") = ""
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(j, "I") = ""
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(j, "J") = ""
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(j, "K") = ""

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(j, "O") = ""
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(j, "P") = ""
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(j, "Q") = ""
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(j, "R") = ""

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(8, "B") = "Hand over the calculator, friends don’t let friends derive drunk."
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(11, "B") = " "
'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Next

TotalPrice = 0
TotalSF = 0
TotalSurCap = 0
TotalCorCap = 0

TileSearch = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(41, "AF") 'starting Point from import
If TileSearch <> "" Then
    For i = 41 To 60
        If TileSearch = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(i, "AF") Then
        'this line shouldnt change once number is in
        'catch = i
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(41, "O") = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(i, "AB")
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(41, "P") = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(i, "AC")
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(41, "Q") = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(i, "AD")
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(41, "A") = TileSearch
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(41, "H") = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(i, "AK")
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(41, "J") = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(i, "AM")
        'need for price pulling
        TotalPrice = TotalPrice + ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(i, "AG")
        TotalSF = TotalSF + ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(i, "AH")
       'this is for bullnose count
        TotalSurCap = TotalSurCap + ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(i, "AL")
        TotalCorCap = TotalCorCap + ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(i, "AQ")
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(41, "D") = TotalPrice
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(41, "I") = TotalSurCap
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(41, "K") = TotalCorCap
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(41, "R") = TotalSF
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(41, "E") = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(41, "V")
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(41, "F") = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(41, "U")
         End If
    Next i
End If

TotalPrice = 0
TotalSF = 0
TotalSurCap = 0
TotalCorCap = 0

    TileSearch = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(42, "AF")
    If TileSearch <> "" And TileSearch <> ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(41, "A") _
And TileSearch <> ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(43, "A") _
And TileSearch <> ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(44, "A") _
And TileSearch <> ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(45, "A") _
And TileSearch <> ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(46, "A") _
And TileSearch <> ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(47, "A") _
And TileSearch <> ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(48, "A") _
And TileSearch <> ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(49, "A") _
And TileSearch <> ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(50, "A") _
And TileSearch <> ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(51, "A") _
And TileSearch <> ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(52, "A") _
And TileSearch <> ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(53, "A") _
And TileSearch <> ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(54, "A") _
And TileSearch <> ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(55, "A") _
And TileSearch <> ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(56, "A") _
And TileSearch <> ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(57, "A") _
And TileSearch <> ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(58, "A") _
And TileSearch <> ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(59, "A") _
And TileSearch <> ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(60, "A") Then
    For i = 41 To 60
        If TileSearch = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(i, "AF") Then
        'this line shouldnt change once number is in
        'catch = i
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(42, "O") = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(i, "AB")
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(42, "P") = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(i, "AC")
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(42, "Q") = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(i, "AD")
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(42, "A") = TileSearch
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(42, "H") = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(i, "AK")
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(42, "J") = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(i, "AM")
        'need for price pulling
        TotalPrice = TotalPrice + ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(i, "AG")
        TotalSF = TotalSF + ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(i, "AH")
       'this is for bullnose count
        TotalSurCap = TotalSurCap + ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(i, "AL")
        TotalCorCap = TotalCorCap + ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(i, "AQ")
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(42, "D") = TotalPrice
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(42, "I") = TotalSurCap
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(42, "K") = TotalCorCap
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(42, "R") = TotalSF
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(42, "E") = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(42, "V")
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(42, "F") = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(42, "U")
         End If
    Next i
End If
```

**Edit: 3-23**
 Question Answered removed double loop error question.

Comment: Okay. You have 2 `For` and only 1 `Next`. You cannot do it. Every `For` ends somewhere... Same goes for `If` - every `If` must have `End If`. And why do you do it? I think I changed your code as you wished? Doesn't my code do the same as your previous?

Comment: Nevermind, I reloaded a previous version and added the set ws change you made and its functioning correctly. Thank you

Comment: Nice to hear. Good luck.

Comment: I spoke too soon. It works only if every line is filled in. if there's a blank line it stops or if it comes to blank line it makes duplicates lines.

Comment: I think you should create a new question so that it would be more understandable. Post your code and if you can - examples how your data looks, what is done after the sub is finished and what you actually want to acheive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the part you needed via introducing a boolean variable `bFlag`.

```
Private Sub FloorWallTileCombo_Click()
Dim TileSearch As String
Dim TotalPrice As Double, TotalSF As Double, TotalSurCap As Double, TotalCorCap As Double
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown")
Dim bFlag As Boolean

ws.Range("A41:A60").Value2 = vbNullString
ws.Range("D41:F60").Value2 = vbNullString
ws.Range("H41:K60").Value2 = vbNullString
ws.Range("O41:R60").Value2 = vbNullString

ws.Cells(8, "B") = "Hand over the calculator, friends don’t let friends derive drunk."
ws.Cells(11, "B") = " "

TotalPrice = 0
TotalSF = 0
TotalSurCap = 0
TotalCorCap = 0

TileSearch = ws.Cells(41, "AF") 'starting Point from import
If TileSearch <> "" Then
    For i = 41 To 60
        If TileSearch = ws.Cells(i, "AF") Then
            'this line shouldnt change once number is in
            ws.Range("O41:Q41").Value = ws.Range("AB" & i & ":AD" & i).Value
            ws.Cells(41, "A") = TileSearch
            ws.Cells(41, "H") = ws.Cells(i, "AK")
            ws.Cells(41, "J") = ws.Cells(i, "AM")
            'need for price pulling
            TotalPrice = TotalPrice + ws.Cells(i, "AG")
            TotalSF = TotalSF + ws.Cells(i, "AH")
            'this is for bullnose count
            TotalSurCap = TotalSurCap + ws.Cells(i, "AL")
            TotalCorCap = TotalCorCap + ws.Cells(i, "AQ")
            ws.Cells(41, "D") = TotalPrice
            ws.Cells(41, "I") = TotalSurCap
            ws.Cells(41, "K") = TotalCorCap
            ws.Cells(41, "R") = TotalSF
            ws.Cells(41, "E") = ws.Cells(41, "V")
            ws.Cells(41, "F") = ws.Cells(41, "U")
        End If
    Next 'i
End If

TotalPrice = 0
TotalSF = 0
TotalSurCap = 0
TotalCorCap = 0

TileSearch = ws.Cells(42, "AF")
For i = 43 To 60
    If Not TileSearch <> ws.Cells(i, "A") Then
        bFlag = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next

If TileSearch <> "" And TileSearch <> ws.Cells(41, "A") And bFlag = False Then
    For i = 41 To 60
        If TileSearch = ws.Cells(i, "AF") Then
            'this line shouldnt change once number is in
            ws.Range("O42:Q42").Value = ws.Range("AB" & i & ":AD" & i).Value
            ws.Cells(42, "A") = TileSearch
            ws.Cells(42, "H") = ws.Cells(i, "AK")
            ws.Cells(42, "J") = ws.Cells(i, "AM")
            'need for price pulling
            TotalPrice = TotalPrice + ws.Cells(i, "AG")
            TotalSF = TotalSF + ws.Cells(i, "AH")
            'this is for bullnose count
            TotalSurCap = TotalSurCap + ws.Cells(i, "AL")
            TotalCorCap = TotalCorCap + ws.Cells(i, "AQ")
            ws.Cells(42, "D") = TotalPrice
            ws.Cells(42, "I") = TotalSurCap
            ws.Cells(42, "K") = TotalCorCap
            ws.Cells(42, "R") = TotalSF
            ws.Cells(42, "E") = ws.Cells(42, "V")
            ws.Cells(42, "F") = ws.Cells(42, "U")
        End If
    Next 'i
End If
```

There is no `End Sub`, so I suppose this subroutine continues. So also please add

```
Set ws = Nothing
```

right before the `End Sub` statement

Comment: I apologize about the delay, I've been out sick and just now got around to  it. I am getting a Object Variable or With Block variable not set

Comment: It happens right at the beginning, I have ws = nothing at the end.

Comment: I changed Dim ws As Worksheet to Dim ws As Worksheets("Breakdown") and now it runs. However its duplicating results but it could be my error I am checking my input of the loop.

Comment: There was my mistake. The line `Dim ws As Worksheet` is OK. But the line `Set ws = ws` is to be changed to `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown")`

Comment: I apologize i updated the Original.

Answer (score 1):

Begin by removing all the unnecessary loops.  Replace:

```
For j = 41 To 60
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(j, "A") = ""
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(j, "D") = ""
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(j, "E") = ""
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(j, "F") = ""

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(j, "H") = ""
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(j, "I") = ""
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(j, "J") = ""
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(j, "K") = ""

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(j, "O") = ""
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(j, "P") = ""
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown").Cells(j, "Q") = ""
Next j
```

with:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakdown")
    .Range("A41:A60") = ""
    .Range("D41:F60") = ""
    .Range("H41:K60") = ""
    .Range("O41:Q60") = ""
End With
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I would mark it as being useful but my rep is too low. ZygD works for this string of code but I am going to definitely use your suggestion for other pages that have unnecessary loops.